# Get last action of a person on a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with the following rows:

```
 NAME                        RFID                  ACTION    TIME       DATE

Kashif Islam            E2001026770D00742340248A    OUT  12:40:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    IN   13:52:00   1/30/2013
Qasim Mehmood           E2001026770D018223202774    IN   13:52:00   1/30/2013
M.Bilal Khan            E2001026770D009522402D80    IN   13:52:00   1/30/2013
Abdul Hameed            E2001026770D0181248019B8    IN   13:52:00   1/30/2013
Usman Tariq             E2001026770D00862570111D    IN   13:52:00   1/30/2013
Dr. Asif Gondal         E2001026770D012426600B32    IN   13:52:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    OUT  13:52:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    IN   13:53:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    OUT  13:53:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    IN   13:53:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    OUT  13:53:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    IN   13:54:00   1/30/2013
Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid    E2001026770D0212267009D3    OUT  13:54:00   1/30/2013
Aamir Hafeez            E2001026770D01952510155B    IN   13:55:00   1/30/2013
Amjad Ali Anjum         E2001026770D024125401476    IN   13:55:00   1/30/2013
Amjad Ali Anjum         E2001026770D024125401476    OUT  13:56:00   1/30/2013
Dr. Asif Gondal         E2001026770D012426600B32    OUT  13:56:00   1/30/2013
Arif Shah               E2001026770D01852370206D    IN   13:56:00   1/30/2013
Fida ul Hassan          E2001026770D02112720095C    IN   13:56:00   1/30/2013
```

Now I want to get the latest `ACTION` on a given date for each person, e.g.:

```
    1/30/2013   13:56:00    OUT Amjad Ali Anjum
    1/30/2013   13:56:00    IN  Arif Shah
    1/30/2013   13:56:00    OUT Dr. Asif Gondal
    1/30/2013   13:54:00    OUT Dr.Arshad Ali Shahid
    1/30/2013   13:56:00    IN  Fida ul Hassan
```

I am using the below query to get it, but I am not getting correct results:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
   row_number() over (partition by personname order by date) rn,
   date,action,time,
   personname

FROM
   AISDb)
SELECT date,time,action,
       personname
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1 AND datestamp = '1/30/2013'
```

Comment: Why are date and time in separate columns? And what does "not getting correct results" mean?

Comment: date and time are in seperate columns and i m not getting corrects results for some records and also it don't get the latest time...so for dr.arshad ali shahid record above...i get time:13:52,...which is not correct and need

Comment: `date and time are in separate columns` yes, I know that. I was asking why.

Comment: Yes, probably. Why are they separate? You can always find all the rows for a particular day using `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, datetime_column) = '20130130';`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you just had the filter in the wrong place and the order by inside the over() clause was all wrong.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
   row_number() over (partition by personname order by time DESC) rn,
   date,action,time,
   personname
FROM
   AISDb
WHERE datestamp = '20130130')
SELECT date,time,action,
       personname
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1;
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/335e4/3)

If you need to break a tie in the case of IN/OUT somehow both recorded at the same time, one way is to break the tie assuming that OUT happened last:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 
   row_number() over (partition by personname order by time DESC, action DESC) rn,
   date,action,time,
   personname
FROM
   AISDb
WHERE datestamp = '20130130')
SELECT date,time,action,
       personname
FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1;
```

[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/335e4/13)

Comment: no i didn't get required result for "dr.arshad ali shahid" record
i require time 13:54 and the above query gives 13:52...see the above table and u will understand.

Comment: @ssaaddii please try harder. I'm pretty sure I understand the problem. I'm also confident that [this query seems to work](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/335e4/3) (once I sorted out your column names).

Comment: i checked it...see action of dr arshad ali shahid...time is right i.e. 13:54..but action is not right...it should be OUT and it is IN...plz see it...i think there may be a mistake in calc row num

Comment: @ssaaddii No, there is no mistake in the calculation of the row number; there is a *tie*. If they were both recorded at the same time, how do you know which one was last?

Comment: @ssaaddii [Here is an example that breaks the tie in the way you say you want, but I have no idea if this will always break the tie correctly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/335e4/13). You may need to use better granularity than minute if this is a realistic occurrence and not just garbage, unrealistic data.

Answer (score 2):

Classic [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. One possible solution:

```
select w.* 
from w
inner join (
    select name, max(time) time
    from w
    where date = '2013-01-30'
    group by Name
) sel on w.Name = sel.Name 
     and w.Time = sel.Time
where w.date = '2013-01-30'
```

Piggy-backing on Aaron's fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/335e4/11

A few considerations:

- You should really *really* have one field to hold both date and time. Filtering, indexing, sorting, all is simpler that way.
- If you have a TIE (two transactions at the same time for same Name), this solution will bring both.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know, that's one of the considerations on my updated answer. OP has to decide which operation to show in case of a tie

Answer (score -1):

As people's responses indicate you need to change the order of the date/time logic to Desc so you get the most recent first. The other thing is you're only partitioning by personname within the CTE so the 1 value is going to be the most recent value regardless of date and then you limit the date outside so you may not have a value that matches. You can fix this a few ways, but I would just add the date to the partitioning logic.

```
WITH    CTE AS 
(
        SELECT  row_number() over (partition by personname, [date]  order by [time] desc, rn desc) rn,
                [date],
                [action],
                [time],
                personname
        FROM   (Select  row_number() over (Order By (Select Null)) rn,
                        [date],
                        [action],
                        [time],
                        personname
                FROM    AISDb)
)
SELECT  [date],
        [action],
        [time],
        personname
FROM    CTE 
WHERE   RN = 1 
AND     datestamp = '1/30/2013'
```

In order to get around the ties I added a nested table that gets a row_number based upon (Select Null). This is a janky workaround that will get the default ordering. If this doesn't work you can't do what you want with you're current inputs and you should add an identity column to capture the order of inserts.

Comment: @AaronBertrand What do you think of this as a solution? Are there pitfalls I'm not considering?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the inner query and the arbitrary row_number() assigned using order by select null. Why would this lead to a predictable tie-breaker any more than not bothering? Unless you know something I don't know where `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` guarantees ordering...

Comment: @AaronBertrand Order By `(Select Null)` will use the default ordering so in the absence of a clustered index it will order them in the order they were added to the table. Essentially if you run `Select * From table` and like the ordering then you can use this method.

Comment: You missed my point. What is "the default ordering"? What happens when you add or change an index? You know that the order you see today for a SELECT without ORDER BY might not be the same tomorrow, right?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yeah, I get that. That's the reason I mentioned the clustered index. Nonclustered indexes don't affect the physical ordering (yeah, I know, no shit sherlock) so they don't change the ordering (at least from the testing I've done). From the testing I did the "default ordering" appears to simply be the order it reads the data and with a `Select *` that is likely to be in the physical order it's written to disk. I suppose if it was heavily fragmented and it used some parallelism to read it that it could change the order. Honestly I don't know but I've seen it used before like this.

Comment: And in the example you gave here, if there is an index on the four columns mentioned, it will likely be used as opposed to the clustered index, since it is skinnier but still has to scan. ***DO NOT RELY ON ORDERING WITHOUT A WELL-DEFINED ORDER BY***.

Comment: @AaronBertrand duhhh ... everyone knows that tables and heaps are FIFO buffers.

Comment: Anyway I just wanted to point out that that was a pitfall you haven't considered (since you asked). If you want to continue ignoring it, and believe that this order based on the clustered index is guaranteed, go ahead - even though there is plenty of evidence to the contrary readily available.

Comment: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2010/10/18/uncertainty-erodes-confidence-so-add-that-order-by-clause.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2012/02/28/why-people-think-some-sql-server-2000-behaviors-live-on-12-years-later.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2010/02/08/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior.aspx

Comment: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2010/06/27/sql-101-without-order-by-order-is-not-guaranteed.aspx

Comment: I can provide more if necessary. But please stop perpetuating a myth that is already altogether too popular.

Comment: Not sure what myth you're referring to or if you're even talking to me. It makes sense that if a Nonclustered index was chosen then it would affect the ordering, but I never said it wouldn't. I know that it is impossible to guarantee the ordering without specifying it and I know this solution isn't sure fire. I guess I should've been more clear... `By default ordering I mean whatever order is chosen by the query processor for the query in the absence of an order by` and I know this can change, but I've observed that it often results in being physically ordered.

Comment: Well, you asked what pitfalls you aren't considering, and that is a pretty major one, since your whole answer revolves around deriving an arbitrary row_number() assigned in completely undefined order. So I'm still not clear what value this solution has over not bothering to break the tie at all, in much less code.

Comment: -1 for assuming default ordering. There is none. At all. Whatsoever.